# remove numbers from URL via url rewriting

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to find a way to rewrite my URLs so that IF the value of the variable p starts with a number the number is removed from the URL and the URL is rewritten with the value of p like so:

```
domain.com/index.php?p=23_Product&ms=0
```

rewritten to:

```
domain.com/Product&ms=0
```

My current htaccess file looks like this and everything works the way I want it to (except for the number removal part):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php\?p=((?!(?:admin|superadmin|[^&]*?edit))[^\s&]+)(?:&(\S+))? [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1?%2 [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ index.php?p=$1 [L,QSA]
```

I tried to make this modification but I get a redirect loop:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php\?p=([0-9]{0,99})(?:&(\S+))? [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%2 [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php\?p=((?!(?:admin|superadmin|[^&]*?edit))[^\s&]+)(?:&(\S+))? [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1?%2 [R=302,L,NE]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^[0-9]{0,99}(.+?)/?$ index.php?p=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Can you tell me what I am doing wrong?
Thanks

Comment: But if you rewrite this URL `domain.com/Product&ms=0` with this pattern `RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ index.php?p=$1 [L,QSA]` you'll get this: `index.php?p=index.php?p=23_Product&ms=0`

Comment: @TiMESPLiNTER I am very new to URL rewriting so I don't doubt there are mistakes... I know the first code works and I just want to remove the numbers that are at the beginning of whatever values of "p" start with a number

Comment: But why do you want to remove number for `p` parameter? Will `http://domain.com/index.php?p=Product` be a valid URI?

Comment: @anubhava no it won't be valid, I simply want it to be rewritten both ways so that the user never sees the numbers that are appended in front of the names of p... if I can rewrite it both ways then it should work, shoudln'it?

Comment: But once number is gone from URI using `R` flag then it can't come back later in internal rewrite URI.

Comment: @anubhava cam you show me how the code would be altered to do that? i can then in my php code make sure that a direct call to a rewritten url without the number will still resolve correctly

Comment: That cannot be managed by rewrite rules unless you allow numbers to be part of pretty URI. There is no need to remove numbers before `Product1

Comment: @anubhava i realize there si no need but i would like to do it ve cause they will look prettier, which is the Point Of url rewriting

Comment: Prettiness is subjective. For SEO purpose `domain.com/23_Product&ms=0` and `domain.com/Product&ms=0` are same. Did you check SO URL of your question where they have question-id and question-title both. **Bottom line** is if your backend needs the number then number must be present in the URL.